# Custom post type menu button color

Tags: custom-post-types

If I create a Custom Post Type I can change the icon used in the dashboard with this

```
    'menu_icon' => [YOUR FILE PATH HERE] . '/images/portfolio-icon.png',  // Icon Path
```

Is it possible to change the color of the button in the dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly what your wanting to do you'll need to override the CSS that is in `/wp-admin/css/colors-fresh.css`.

To change the default state of a single button you can just add CSS like this

```
#menu-posts-testimonials-widget {
  background: red;
}
```

this is an example with the `testimonial widget plugin` you can inspect the element to find out the id of the element and base your CSS off that.